# Prove that the given sum is not Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

Book browsing *Banach spaces of Analytic function* of the author Kenneth Hoffman on page 74 is one example. This example is compiled in this way:

Prove that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}e^{in\theta}
$$

is not the Fourier series of a finite measure on the circle.

I would like to know how is the solution communities in this example. Previously, thank you for solving.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the theorem on p.23. It says that a formal Fourier series is the Fourier series of a finite measure if and only if the Cesaro means are bounded in $L^1$. Check this.